# Encapsulating Powershell Functions

Tags: function, powershell, scoping

I am at a lost as to how to perform the following task. As with class members in OOP, we are allowed to hide away implementation with a private modifier. My goal is to create a base powershell function that contains logic that is used by several functions for code reuse while hiding away that function from global access. According to the following reference https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-scopes.html , the following scopes are available Global, Script, and Private. My labeling of the functions do not produce the desired result. The ecapsulated function should work as shown below.

```
function Invoke-VMDoSomething {
    Invoke-PrivateMiniFunc
}

function Invoke-VMDoSomethingElse {
    Invoke-PrivateMiniFunc
}

function Invoke-PrivateMiniFunc {
    ###BaseReuseable code
}
```

Hypothetical Command Prompt

```
PS > Invoke-VMDoSomething <<<Invoke-PrivateMiniFunc Executes successfully

PS > Invoke-VMDoSomethingElse <<<Invoke-PrivateMiniFunc Executes successfully 

PS > Invoke-PrivateMiniFunc <<<Fails Cannot find Such Commandlet -- Desired result.
```

How can I implement this convention and do I need to store the functions in a .psm1 file vice a ps1 file? Is it even possible?

Comment: https://xainey.github.io/2016/powershell-classes-and-concepts/

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The link talks about how to create classes,  not function scoping. Please thoroughly read the post. I only mentioned classes and OOP as an example.

Comment: As per documentation you need to specify that the function is global - does Function Global:InvokePrivateMinifunc { ## Reusable code } not work?

Comment: All of the functions work with the Global scope modifier. However, per my design specs, I want Global:InvokePrivateMinifunc { ## Reusable code } to be seen only by the functions inhabiting the module  which would therefore require it "not" to be global. Scoping may not be the solution to the effect of hiding away InvokePirivateMiniFunc so that it is encapsulated only to the knowledge of other functions in the module. As stated in the third line in "Hypothetical Command Prompt", it must fail. Are you saying that I should make only Invoke-VMDoSomething and Invoke-VMDoSomethingElse global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not exactly what you are after, but you can hide functions inside a module.

In your case, create a new file and save it as *.psm1 (for demo I call it `InvokeModule.psm1`)

```
function Invoke-VMDoSomething {
    Invoke-PrivateMiniFunc
}

function Invoke-VMDoSomethingElse {
    Invoke-PrivateMiniFunc
}

function Invoke-PrivateMiniFunc {
    Write-Host "Called by: $((Get-PSCallStack)[1].FunctionName)" 
}

# export the functions you want to make available and leave out 
# the functions you want to keep hidden (but available to the functions in the module)

Export-ModuleMember -Function Invoke-VMDoSomething, Invoke-VMDoSomethingElse
```

The last command `Export-ModuleMember` defines what functions you want exposed en what not.

Next, in another file import that module.

In there, only the Exported functions are visible/callable but the `Invoke-PrivateMiniFunc` is not:

```
Import-Module 'D:\InvokeModule.psm1'

Invoke-VMDoSomething      # works as expected

Invoke-VMDoSomethingElse  # works as expected

Invoke-PrivateMiniFunc    # errors out
```

Result:

```
Called by: Invoke-VMDoSomething
Called by: Invoke-VMDoSomethingElse
Invoke-PrivateMiniFunc : The term 'Invoke-PrivateMiniFunc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:7 char:1
+ Invoke-PrivateMiniFunc
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-PrivateMiniFunc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. A bit of an verbose step...but it works! I think that this convention ought be more cleaner in future PS versions. Very useful for code maintenance.